# AWS free tier account providing 30GB storage to create an instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

In AWS free tier account providing 30GB storage to create an instance, if creating another instance with the same account is it chargeable?

Answer (score 1):

There is **no such thing as a free AWS account**. However, there is a [free usage tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/) that provides a certain amount of select services at no charge, typically for the first 12 months of the account.

The free usage tier does include **30GB of EBS storage**. This means that the first 30GB of EBS storage for an entire month is free every month. This could be used as 60GB for half a month, 120GB for a quarter of a month or 30GB for the whole month. This logic applies to all services -- AWS services are typically calculated on an hourly basis, so the hours can be used in parallel if desired.

In fact, a recent change means that EBS is **now charged per-second**, so if you delete the volumes when they are not necessary, you will even gain the benefit of part-hours.

Mind you, some of the costs are quite low even if you exceed the free usage tier. In US regions, the cost is $0.10/GB/month, so an extra 30GB volume for the month would cost $3.00.